# Read file and count words

Tags: c++, file

Try to read a file and output it into lines and count the number of characters, lines, and non whitespace characters, and words.  Im close to finish i think but I cannot figure out how to count the number of words. Also it cuts of the first letter of every line except first when i run it.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int line_number = 0;
    char words;
    int number_of_spaces = 0;
    int number_of_lines = 0;
    int number_of_characters = 0;
    int number_of_words = 0;
    int count = 0;
    char character;
    string word;
    int n = 0;
    string line;
    ifstream myFile;
    string file;
    cout <<"Enter file name: ";
    getline(cin,file);


    myFile.open(file.c_str());
    char output[100];



    if(myFile.is_open())
    {

        cout << " " << endl;

        while( getline ( myFile, line ) )
        {
            line_number += 1;
            cout << "Line: " << line_number << " ";
            cout << line << endl;

            number_of_characters += line.length();

            for (int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++)
            {
                if(line[i] == ' ' || line[i] == '/t')
                {
                    number_of_spaces++;
                }
            }

            myFile.get(character);
            if (character != ' ' || character != '/n')
            {
                number_of_lines += 1;
            }


        }




        cout << " " << endl;
        cout << number_of_characters << " characters, " << endl;
        cout << number_of_characters - number_of_spaces << " non whitespace characters, " << endl; 
        cout << number_of_words << " words, " << endl;
        cout << number_of_lines << " lines." << endl;

    }

    myFile.close();

    system("Pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `getline` consumes the whole line. So your call to `myFile.get()` is why you lose the first character of every subsequent line. Also, it's `'\n'`, not `'/n'`.

Comment: You can remove these lines: `myFile.get(character);
            if (character != ' ' || character != '/n')
            {
                number_of_lines += 1;
            }`

Answer (score 1):

You can read a file word by word by using the >> operator. So this code should work:

```
std::string word;
int counter = 0;
while (myFile >> word)
{
    counter++;
}
```